# How to increase carousel-indicators spacing

Tags: angularjs, carousel

I am new to angularjs carousel concept . I would like to increase the space of carousel Indicator. Below is my code in angularjs kindly please do help me out in this.

```
 <div class="carouselContainer"">
        <carousel interval="interval">
                <div class ="carousel-inner">
        <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">

            <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" onclick="javascript:location.href='#fluid pb_heroTile'">

        </slide>
            <!--<a href="#"><u>#</u></a>-->
                    </div>
        </carousel>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the solution. we have to use:

```
.carousel-indicators li, .carousel-indicators li.active {
  margin: 0px 7px !important;
}
```